# Add Search button in intl-tel-input

Tags: c#, jquery, intl-tel-input

I am using intltelInput to get the country code in contact numbers.
I find it difficult to choose countries which are listed far below.So can anyone help me to add search option in the dropdowns.
below is my code.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Reference Contact No.</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReferenceContactNo, new { @Class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

J-Query Code:

```
$("#ReferenceContactNo").intlTelInput({
        separateDialCode:'false'
    });
```

Comment: I was trying to implement the same but didn't find any solution. I tried select2 with intl-tel-input but didn't get success. Do you have any solution?

Comment: I tried everything I could find. But there was no solutions that could fit my requirement. So I left as it is for now.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will share If I found anything related to it.

Comment: I found the same functionality but in Angular using Intl-tel-input
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-a4crnj

Comment: Thank you . But I am using JQuery so it is quiet difficult for me to understand your angular code.